# Adapter not showing data obtained from Parse.com through AsyncTask

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-asynctask, adapter

I am trying to obtain some data from Parse.com through an `AsyncTaskRunner`. ANd then I intend to show them in a `ListView`. My custom adapter code is attached below :

```
public class ParseObjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    LayoutInflater mInflater;
    List<ParseObject> parseArray;
    DBShoppingHelper mydb2;

    public ParseObjectAdapter(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater) {
        mContext = context;
        mInflater = inflater;
        parseArray = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        try {
            return parseArray.size();
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ParseObject getItem(int position) { return parseArray.get(position); }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public String getObjectId(int position){
        return getItem(position).getObjectId();
    }

    public void sortByExpiry()
    {
        Comparator<ParseObject> comparator = new Comparator<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ParseObject lhs, ParseObject rhs) {
            return ((Integer) lhs.getInt("expiresIn")).compareTo(rhs.getInt("expiresIn"));
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(parseArray, comparator);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        // Inflate the custom row layout from your XML.
        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        // create a new "Holder" with subviews
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemNameView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        holder.itemExpiryView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_expiry);

        // Taking care of the buttons
        holder.editButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_edit);
        holder.deleteButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_delete);
        holder.shoppingListButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_shopping);

        // hang onto this holder for future recycling
        convertView.setTag(holder);

        int expiry = getItem(position).getInt("expiresIn");

        if (expiry <= 0) {
            holder.itemExpiryView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(255,80,54));
        }

        // Set listener on the buttons
        holder.editButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Edit Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ParseObject p = getItem(position);

                Intent goToAddItem = new Intent(mContext,ItemAddPage.class);
                goToAddItem.putExtra("catg_passed", p.getString("category"));
                goToAddItem.putExtra("update_flag", "YES");
                goToAddItem.putExtra("name passed", p.getString("itemName"));
                goToAddItem.putExtra("expires_in_passed", p.getString("expiresIn"));
                goToAddItem.putExtra("price_passed", p.getString("itemPrice"));
                mContext.startActivity(goToAddItem);
            }
        });

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ParseObject p = getItem(position);

                String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
                ParseQuery itemToBeDeleted = new ParseQuery("Items");
                itemToBeDeleted.whereEqualTo("ACL", p.getACL());
                itemToBeDeleted.whereEqualTo("objectId", p.getObjectId());
                final Date deletionDate = new Date();

                itemToBeDeleted.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> Items, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + Items.size() + " scores");
                            if (Items.size() == 1) {
                                ParseObject itemToDelete = Items.get(0);
                                itemToDelete.put("deleted", true);
                                itemToDelete.put("deletedOn", deletionDate);
                                itemToDelete.saveEventually();
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                parseArray.remove(p);
                sortByExpiry();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        holder.shoppingListButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                ParseObject p = getItem(position);
                String add_to_list = p.getString("itemName");

                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
                String add_date = sdf.format(new Date());
                System.out.println(add_date);
                mydb2.insertItem(add_to_list, add_date);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Item added to shopping list", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        ParseObject p = getItem(position);
        String name2 = p.getString("itemName");
        Integer ex = p.getInt("expiresIn");
        String days_s ="";

        if (ex == 0) {
            days_s = "Expires today" ;
        }
        else if (ex == -1) {
            days_s = "Expired yesterday";
        }
        else if (ex < 0) {
            days_s = "Expired " + Math.abs(ex) + " days ago";
        }
        else if (ex == 1) {
            days_s = "Expires tomorrow";
        }
        else {
            days_s = "Expires in " + ex + " days";
        }

        holder.itemNameView.setText(name2);
        holder.itemExpiryView.setText(days_s);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        Intent viewItem = new Intent(v.getContext(), ItemAddPage.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(viewItem);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        public TextView itemNameView;
        public TextView itemExpiryView;
        public Button editButton;
        public Button deleteButton;
        public Button shoppingListButton;
    }

    public void updateData(List<ParseObject> arrayPassed) {
        // update the adapter's data set
        parseArray = arrayPassed;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

This is the method from which I am calling it..

```
public class WelcomeParse extends Activity {

    ListView currentListView;
    List<ParseObject> currentList;

    ParseObjectAdapter itemAdder;

    String catg;
    DBShoppingHelper mydb2;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.left_in, R.anim.right_out);
        setTheme(android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_DarkActionBar);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        itemAdder = new ParseObjectAdapter(this, getLayoutInflater());

        mydb2 = new DBShoppingHelper(this);

        AsyncTaskAllItems runner = new AsyncTaskAllItems();
        runner.execute();
        // itemAdder.notifyDataSetChanged();

               this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
    }

    public class AsyncTaskAllItems extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        private String resp;
        private Integer numItems = 0;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                ParseQuery itemsAll = new ParseQuery("Items");
                itemsAll.whereEqualTo("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
//                itemsByCategory.whereEqualTo("category", catg);

                itemsAll.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                    @Override
                    public void done(List<ParseObject> Items, ParseException e) {
                        if (e == null) {
                            Log.d("score", "Retrieved " + Items.size() + " scores");
                            Log.d("owner", ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getUsername());
                            // HERE SIZE is 0 then 'No Data Found!'
                            numItems = Items.size();
                            if (numItems > 0) {
                                currentList = Items;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Log.d("score", "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                        }
                    }
                });

                resp = "Done";
            }
//            catch (InterruptedException e) {
//                e.printStackTrace();
//                resp = e.getMessage();
//            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                resp = e.getMessage();
            }

            return resp;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            currentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_list);
            itemAdder.updateData(currentList);
            if (numItems > 0) {
                itemAdder.sortByExpiry();
            }
            currentListView.setAdapter(itemAdder);
            // onWindowFocusChanged(true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {           
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
        }
    }
}
```

I do not get any error and the log correctly shows the number of items that should be retrieved. But the view does not get updated with the relevant data.
COuld anyone please show me where I am wrong? Anything else you need, just let me know. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try after replacing

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        currentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_list);
        itemAdder.updateData(currentList);
        if (numItems > 0) {
            itemAdder.sortByExpiry();
        }
        currentListView.setAdapter(itemAdder);
        // onWindowFocusChanged(true);
    }
```

With

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            currentListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.all_list);
            currentListView.setAdapter(itemAdder);
           itemAdder.updateData(currentList);
            if (numItems > 0) {
                itemAdder.sortByExpiry();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Tried, did not help :(